# Make GET Request C# in Android Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can you give me example to do GET request in Android Xamarin Studio on non-main thread because when i make request using the System.Net  application freezes to time when server give response.

Comment: Use the methods returning a Task (they end in Async). I prefer to use HttpClient but for simple Get using WebClient you can use DownloadStringTaskAsync method.

Comment: Using Xamarin means that things like web requests are the same as in any .NET platform.  There are hundreds of examples on SO and elsewhere of different ways to do this - I've linked to one example for you